Formula for adding value in each cycle for compound interest
In Google Sheets, I know the formula for compound interest, for example:
10000*(1+10%)^n

10000: start-up cash
10%: interest rate
n: interest cycle
But what if I also add 10000 cash each month?
What will the formula look like?
The interest cycle is per month, and I'm also only looking for per-month basis result

Use reduce(), like this:
=let( 
  start, 10000, 
  increment, 10000, 
  percent, 10%, 
  n, 12, 
  reduce(start, sequence(n), lambda(acc, i, 
    (acc + increment) * (percent + 100%) 
  )) 
)

For a step-to-step breakdown of how the result progresses from period to period, replace reduce() with scan(), or use this formula that creates a two-column table to show how it goes:
=let( 
  start, 10000, 
  increment, 10000, 
  percent, 10%, 
  n, 12, 
  reduce({ start, 0 }, sequence(n), lambda(acc, i, let( 
    principal, single(chooserows(acc, -1)), 
    newPrincipal, (principal + increment) * (percent + 100%), 
    vstack( 
      acc, 
      hstack(newPrincipal, i) 
    ) 
  ))) 
)




principal
period




10,000.00
0


22,000.00
1


35,200.00
2


49,720.00
3


65,692.00
4


83,261.20
5


102,587.32
6


123,846.05
7


147,230.66
8


172,953.72
9


201,249.10
10


232,374.00
11


266,611.41
12



See
let(),
reduce()
and
sequence().

The for replying! The formula is amazing, but I think there is some misunderstanding maybe?

For example, the first month is 10000 * 1+10%, and the second month is the previous (answer +10000)*(1+10%), so from the formula the result is not the same as my manual calculation

For ref., the answer I got from the formula after 12 months is 62768.6, but from my manual calculation is 235227

Edited the answer to fix a typo and add a breakdown.

close enough, that's amazing!

TL;DR
=INDEX(FV(10%,SEQUENCE(12),-10000,,1)) 

FV Function
Sheets' FV function calculates the future value of an investment, based on an initial investment, ongoing contributions, or both.
Syntax: 
FV(rate, periods, pmt_amt,[present_value],[end_or_beginning])
Single Result

Lump Sum
=FV(rate,periods,,present_value,1)
=FV(10%,12,,-10000,1)
=31,384.28


Monthly Contributions
=FV(rate,periods,pmt_amt,,1)
=FV(10%,12,-10000,,1)
=235,227.12



Array of Results
The FV function is placed inside an array function and the periods' argument is supplied as an array comprised of a sequence of numbers from 1-12:
=SEQUENCE(12)
={1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12}


Lump Sum
=INDEX(FV(rate,{periods},,present_value,1))
=INDEX(FV(10%,SEQUENCE(12),,-10000,1)) 
={11000;12100;13310;14641;16105.10;17715.61;19487.17; 
  21435.89;23579.48;25937.42;28531.17;31384.28} 


Monthly Contributions
=INDEX(FV(rate,SEQUENCE(PERIODS),pmt_amt,,1))
=INDEX(FV(10%,SEQUENCE(12),-10000,,1))  
={11000; 23100;36410;51051;67156.10;84871.71; 104358.88;
  125794.77; 149374.25; 175311.67; 203842.84; 235227.12} 



